# Typescript import from sibling folder - cannot find module

Tags: typescript, import, module, bundle

Importing modules from other folder causes typescript errors.
I have a project with similar structure:

```
 - src
    - tsconfig.json
    - types
      - math.types.ts
    - utils
      - addNumbers.ts
 - playwright
    - tsconfig.json
    - dashboard.page.ts
```

- `src` folder has react app in typescript and some utils that could be used in playwright
- `playwright` has e2e tests for the application

Now, when I import something from `src` folder (for example `addNumbers`) in `playwright/dashboard.page.ts` file and then run command (in playwright folder):

> tsc -p tsconfig.json

I get:

```
../src/utils/addNumbers.ts:4:45 - error TS2307: Cannot find module 'types/math.types' or its corresponding type declarations.

import { SomeNumberType } from 'types/math.types';
```

Imports work fine when I run tsc in `src` folder, everything is broken when I start tsc in `playwright` folder.

Here is `tsconfig.json` from playwright folder:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "strict": true,                                     
      "target": "es2017",                                  
      "module": "commonjs",
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "moduleResolution": "node",                        
      "baseUrl": ".",                                      
      "esModuleInterop": true,                             
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,           
      "paths": {                                       
        "*": ["*", "tests/*"]
      },
      "noEmit": true                       
    }
}
```

Did I miss anything?

Comment: Could you provide the contents of your playwright tsconfig?

Comment: @Amanda Sure, I added the config file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your `playwright\tsconfig.json`, Typescript is throwing `Cannot find module 'types/math.types' or its corresponding type declarations` because it doesn't know about the `src` folder. When `tsc` runs, it uses the location of the `tsconfig.json` (`playwright`) as its scope unless it's instructed otherwise.

You can instruct Typescript that the `src` directory exists and where to find it when it's used as an import.

Here are a few ways, there are more I'm not including here since they don't seem applicable and this is already lengthy:

1. [compilerOptions.files](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#files) - Explicitly list files for Typescript to include. This doesn't seem like it'd be practical for your use case given the number of files and Typescript will process them as part of the `playwright` `tsc`.
2. [compilerOptions.include](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#include) - If you add `src` to includes, `tsc` will process your `src` files when you run in the `playwright` folder. Probably not what you want since you're not sharing a `tsconfig` between the two directories.
3. [Path Aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) - You could add a path alias for `src` and use that for imports in the `playwright` directory. One major downside is Typescript can be happy with these while compiler/runtime fail if compiler/node/etc doesn't also know about those aliases. See [paths module reference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules/reference.html#paths) for some examples that illustrate this well.
4. [Project References](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/project-references.html) - The `playwright\tsconfig.json` provides a project reference to `src`. If `src` isn't already built when `tsc` is run for `playwright`, `tsc` will build `src` from `src\tsconfig.json`. The `src\tsconfig.json` should have `composite` set to `true`. If `rootDir` and `declaration` aren't set, it will default `rootDir` to the directory containing the `tsconfig.json` and `declaration` to `true`. `declarationMap` isn't required for this setup, but is useful for IDE debugging. The main change you'd make in your workflow would be using the build command `tsc -b tsconfig.json` instead of `tsc -p tsconfig.json`.

The linked documentation points out implementation details and caveats for each option that could impact specific projects.

**Option #3 Example**

`playwright\tsconfig.json`

```json
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      "strict":true,
      "target":"es2017",
      "module":"commonjs",
      "skipLibCheck":true,
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "baseUrl":".",
      "esModuleInterop":true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames":true,
      "paths":{
         "@src/*":[
            "../src/*"
         ],
         "*":[
            "*",
            "tests/*"
         ]
      },
      "noEmit":true
   }
}
```

Import in `playwright` directory with `@src/types/...`

**Option #4 Example**

`playwright\tsconfig.json`

```json
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      "strict":true,
      "target":"es2017",
      "module":"commonjs",
      "skipLibCheck":true,
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "baseUrl":".",
      "esModuleInterop":true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames":true,
      "paths":{
         "*":[
            "*",
            "tests/*"
         ]
      },
      "noEmit":true
   },
   "references":[
      {
         "path":"../src"
      }
   ]
}
```

`src\tsconfig.json`

```json
{
   "compilerOptions":{
      "_comment": "Include your other compiler options",
      "composite":true,
      "declaration":true,
      "rootDir":".",
      "declarationMap":true
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a React App you can't access folders outside of **src**, are you trying to reuse some module?

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have e2e in playwright folder and want to reuse some utils from src there.